# Storing GTIN/EAN values with PostgreSQL. Which data type to use?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, datatypes

I am building a product database and I need to store GTIN/EAN (Global Trade Item Number/European Article Number) values. Probably except GTIN-14 as it does not seem to be used at retail sales? I read the first digit is used to show some packing information but it is not globally agreed which numeric value represents what exactly?

Anyway, I tried to find out how they work to understand which column type would be appropriate. I used `bigint` when I started my little project. But now I wanted to investigate the issue deeper.

https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/barcodes/GS1_General_Specifications.pdf Page 31 says:

> Note: GTINs may be stored with or without leading zeroes in the same
>   database field, depending on the requirements of the particular
>   application.
>
> Note: A GTIN-12 may start with one, two or three leading zeros. These
>   zeroes are meaningful since they are part of the U.P.C. Company
>   prefix, and therefore these must be preserved when storing the GTIN-12
>   in a database field. For the list of U.P.C. Prefix ranges see section
>   1.4

https://www.gtin.info/ says:

> GTIN is term referring to how the data is stored, i.e., padding the
>   item number with zeroes to a uniform length.

https://www.gs1.dk/media/1246/udi-guideline.pdf Page 14 says:

> GTINs should be represented in software applications as 14 digits by
>   right justifying and zero-filling to the left as appropriate.  In
>   order to preserve any leading zeros that may be present, the GTIN
>   field should be represented ina database as a textfield, not as a
>   numeric field.

https://www.barcodefaq.com/1d/upc-ean/ says:

> To be fully GTIN compliant, all UPC and EAN numbers should be stored
>   in databases as 14-digit numbers and filled in with zeros for the
>   spaces to the left as shown in Fig: 1. For example, a UPC-A barcode of
>   123456789012 would be represented as 00123456789012 in the database of
>   a GTIN compliant system.

Then I found that PostgreSQL has a module for this called `[isn][1]`. There it says:

> Internally, all these types use the same representation (a 64-bit
>   integer), and all are interchangeable.

First of all, I did not quite understand why one would need to store zeros in database if they are for padding only. It made no sense to me. (except for GTIN-12)

So, I was also thinking 64-bit integer sounds a reasonable type to store EAN values as I used `bigint`. Now I am thinking should I have used `isn` extension? But I am using Doctrine on PHP/Symfony and it  may be difficult to get it to understand `ean13` column type and need to do custom mapping etc.

Perhaps somebody can tell if simply using `bigint` could cause troubles in the long run? I thought GTIN-14 can contain all other types and I do not necessarily need conversion between types in the database end. So I don't think there should be any problems but perhaps somebody else may have hands on experience? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're not going to perform arithmetic calculation upon product codes (at least I hope you won't), there is no reason to store the values as numeric. Store them as strings.

Comment: Store it as a string. All of the big ERP systems do

Comment: mustaccio so you think for example ID values should be stored as string because you never do arithmetic calculations on them? That is a very weak argument. Philᵀᴹ any links? at least the PostgreSQL database developers think bigint is the way to go. The problem is that it is much easier and faster to access bigint values compared to variable or fixed length string. They occupy only 8bytes an entry while 14character string will take 14bytes and database can index bigint much more efficiently.

Comment: How much data are you planning on storing? 99.99% of systems don't need the speed of 8/14 savings.

Comment: You're not asking about any old IDs. You're asking about GTIN/EAN codes specifically, which the GS1 specification defines as combinations of strings.

Comment: Colin, the size difference is not much between 8byte vs 14byte but lookup speed will effect simultaneous access to the table. I would rather use an integer column for ID. I am planning to store all the GTIN ever existed for a product in the world.
mustaccio, i still think it is better to store it as `bigint` and for cases with leading zeros, there can be a column `leading_zeros` which is normally null. Because there won't be same `bigint` GTIN ever with or without leading zeros. In that sense, they behave same as integers. Using `bigint` is the most efficient approach.

Comment: You seem to already have your own answer and reject arguments in favour of alternatives, including source standards, why ask the question at all?

Comment: @yurtesen: you don't need to store the number of leading zeros if you store the GTIN as a number. You just have to (left) pad the number with zeros to 12 digits when you display it.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes I had made my mind as I already said in my question that I decided to use a 64bit integer. What I am asking is (as you can read in last paragraph) an example of a functional problem of why a 64bit integer is NOT suitable (besides exception of GTIN12 with leading zeros). I don't think it is a good enough reason to use string on an ID field because one does not do math , or in one document `string` word is used to define the value. Because in other places it is also defined as a `number` as in GTIN (Global Trade Item Number).